# String.prototype.isRepeated

Tags: code-golf, string

**UPDATE** : [isaacg's Pyth submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37863/31414) is the winner!

---

Many of you must have heard that there is a cooler version of JavaScript in town (read ES6) which has a method `String.prototype.repeat` so that you can do

```
"Hello, World!".repeat(3)
```

and get

```
"Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!"
```

as the output.

Your job is to write a function or a program in a **language of your choice** which detects if a string has been gone under such transformation.

i.e. The input string can be represented as an exact `n` times repetition of a smaller string. The output (as function's return statement or STDOUT) should be truthy if the string can be or falsy if the string cannot be represented as a repetition of smaller string.

Some sample input:

```
"asdfasdfasdf"  // true
"asdfasdfa"     // false
"ĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴ"     // true
"ĴĴĴ123ĴĴĴ123"  // true
"abcdefgh"      // false
```

Note that the last input is false, thus **`n` should be greater than `1`**

**Complete rules**

- Write a function/program in any language to input (via function argument/command line args/STDIN) a string
- Return/Print truthy value if the given string is formed via an exact repetition of a smaller string, repeating at least twice.
- Maximum size of the input string is ideally Infinity
- String can have all possible ASCII characters
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so smallest code in characters wins.

Comment: What should "" - the empty string - return? (It contains an infinite number of copies of the empty string.)

Comment: @billpg falsy value

Comment: Are you tie-breaking by votes? The common practice is earlier submission I think (well, the first one that got golfed down to the tying score). But I'm not sure that's written down as the default tie-breaker anywhere, so ultimately it's up to you.

Comment: Time between their posting is only 30 minutes. I will not consider that to be enough for winning :) . Since that time won't change now, but votes can, I went with votes

Comment: This question should be renamed into xnor :) He is the man!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9

```
/:+zz1_1z
```

Or

```
}z:+zz1_1
```

These are both close translations of @xnor's python answer, except that they take input from STDIN and print it. The first is equivalent to:

```
z = input()
print((z+z)[1:-1].count(z))
```

0 for False, 1 for True.

The second line is equivalent to:

```
z = input()
print(z in (z+z)[1:-1])
```

False for False, True for True.

Pyth's official compiler had a bug related to the second one, which I just patched, so the first is my official submission.

Comment: I was just searching for a way to inform you about that bug (the Boolean doesn't get printed). Didn't think of the first and using `x` was too long...

Comment: Yeah, the bug is fixed now. Also, if you want to report bugs, a good way might be to open an issue on the github site, here: https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/issues

Comment: Oh, *there* it is. I don't know my way around GitHub, and I never noticed the navigation panel on the right...

Answer (score 86):

### Python (24)

```python
lambda s:s in(s+s)[1:-1]
```

Checks if the string is a substring of itself concatenated twice, eliminating the first and last characters to avoid trivial matches. If it is, it must be a nontrivial cyclic permutation of itself, and thus the sum of repeated segments.

Comment: Oh dear, that's so much better than my trivial solution...

Comment: A trivial translation into Golfscript yields 10 chars: `..+);(;\?)`

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works. Can you give a manually explained example of how this would handle a string?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs take `abcabc`. `s+s` turns it into `abcabcabcabc`. the `[1:-1]` chops of the two ends to yield `bcabcabcabcab`. and then `s in ...` tries to find `abcabc` as a substring of that. This substring can't be found in either of the original half, because they have both been shortened, so it must span both halves. In particular, it must have its own end before its start, which implies that it must be made up of identical (repeated) substrings.

Comment: Won't this fail on two character strings such as `ab`?

Comment: You chop it after you double it. `ab` becomes `abab` becomes `ba`, so it returns false, while `aa` becomes `aaaa` becomes `aa`, which returns true.

Comment: (how) will it work with 3 copies? for example, "qweqweqwe"

Comment: @SargeBorsch It works just the same: `qweqweqwe` in `weqweqweqweqweqw` is `True`.

Answer (score 30):

### Regex (ECMAScript flavour), 11 bytes

Sounds like a job for regex!

```
^([^]+)\1+$
```

[Test it here.](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5417583975622d4df7be0a00)

I've chosen ECMAScript, because it's the only flavour (I know) in which `[^]` matches any character. In all others, I'd either need a flag to change the behaviour of `.` or use `[\s\S]` which is three characters longer.

Depending on how we're counting the flag, that *could* of course be a byte shorter. E.g. if we're counting pattern + flags (e.g. ignoring delimiters), the PCRE/Perl equivalent would be

```
/^(.+)\1+$/s
```

Which is 10 bytes, ignoring the delimiters.

[Test it here.](http://regex101.com/r/qZ0jP3/1)

This matches only strings which consist of at least two repetitions of some substring.

Here is a full 26-byte ES6 function, but I maintain that regular expression submissions are generally valid:

```
f=s->/^([^]+)\1+$/.test(s)
```

Comment: `^(.+)\1+$` works for me, which is 9 bytes. It doesn't work for you ?

Comment: @Optimizer Try a string with line breaks.

Comment: I tried `asd\nasd\nasd\n` . It works

Comment: @Optimizer http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5417fb2475622d4df7e70a00 doesn't seem to work for me (and it shouldn't)

Comment: Yup, that doesn't work. Maybe it escapes the `\ ` when I write `\n` manually

Comment: @Optimizer Well, the other way round: that tester doesn't understand escape sequences at all (and why would it), so `\n` is just two ASCII characters like any other ones.

Comment: I would expect a regex matcher to not escape strings. When I test in web console or scratchpad, `\n` is treated as single character.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good point. I never thought about that.

Comment: The 10-byte version on regex101.com (complete with explanation): http://regex101.com/r/qZ0jP3/1

Comment: @Ajedi32 oh yeah, that's actually where I tested it. Forgot to add the link. Thanks!

Comment: @Ajedi32 It can also be done [in 10 bytes](https://regex101.com/r/qZ0jP3/2) using `\X`: `^(\X+)\1+$`

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, 9

```
q__+)@+#)
```

Similar to xnor's idea.

```
q      " Read input. ";
__+    " Duplicate twice and concatenate them together. ";
)      " Remove the last character of the longer string. ";
@+     " Insert that character at the beginning of the shorter string. ";
#)     " Find the shorter string in the longer string, and increase by one. ";
```

Comment: +1 obligated to upvote this ahead of [my own CJam answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37861/11259)

Comment: Why the need for the final `)`?  I think its reasonable to have -1 mean FALSE and >=0 mean TRUE

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I think 0 is falsy in CJam... for operators like `g` and `?`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Whether it's needed ultimately depends on the OP, but strictly speaking only zero is considered falsy in CJam.

Comment: @user23013 @Dennis But what about the `#` find operator?  Surely the result of that is also "truthy" from the success vs failure perspective?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: The fact that `#` returns a truthy value on failure is a real annoyance. Nine times out of ten, I don't need the actual index; I just want to know if there's a match. In a sense, you're right. I guess I've just learned to put up with the extra byte it adds to my answers...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Truthy and falsy usually means the value can be converted to boolean as true or false, which shouldn't be different for different operations. But well, the CJam documentation didn't mention what is truthy or falsy, or anything related to boolean data types.

Comment: @Dennis I think this is good discussion, so I've taken it to meta http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey

Answer (score 8):

### APL, 11

```
2<+/x⍷,⍨x←⍞
```

**Explanation**
`⍞` takes string input from screen
`x←` assigns to variable `x`
`,⍨` concatenates the string with itself
`x⍷` searches for `x` in the resulting string. Returns an array consisting of 1's in the starting position of a match and 0's elsewhere.
`+/` sums the array
`2<` check if the sum is greater than 2 (as there will be 2 trivial matches)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 10 bytes

I caught the CJam bug.  My first answer, so probably can be golfed some more:

```
q__+(;);\#
```

Outputs -1 for FALSE and a number >=0 for TRUE

Comment: Welcome to the club!

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript, 10 bytes

```
..+(;);\?)
```

Yet another implementation of xnor's clever idea.

Comment: Hahaha, I just posted this a minute ago: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37851/string-prototype-isrepeated#comment86713_37855 . I thought about posting it as an answer, but I thought that trivial translations are uninteresting.

Comment: I even checked for new answers this time, but not for new comments... Your code is missing the `)` though; when there's not match, it will print `-1`. If you're going to post that as an answer, I'll gladly delete mine.

Comment: I added the `)` just before you posted your answer (I edited the comment)

Comment: I don't care about rep or anything, so I'll just let you have the answer ;-).

Comment: Your call. I've hit the rep cap anyway... :P

Comment: Improved version (in CJam): `q__+)@+#)`. It doesn't work in GolfScript.

Comment: @user23013: Not again. I was just going to post that! There are too many CJammers out there by now... :P

Comment: @user23013: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Python - <s>59</s> 57

```
lambda s:any([s*n==s[:n]*len(s)for n in range(2,len(s))])
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pure bash, 30 bytes

Simple port of [@xnor's clever answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37855/11259):

```
[[ ${1:1}${1:0: -1} =~ "$1" ]]
```

Exit code is 0 for TRUE and 1 for FALSE:

```
$ for s in 'Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!' 'asdfasdfasdf' 'asdfasdfa' 'ĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴ' 'ĴĴĴ123ĴĴĴ123' 'abcdefgh'; do echo "./isrepeated.sh "\"$s\"" returns $(./isrepeated.sh "$s"; echo $?)"; done
./isrepeated.sh "Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!" returns 0
./isrepeated.sh "asdfasdfasdf" returns 0
./isrepeated.sh "asdfasdfa" returns 1
./isrepeated.sh "ĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴĴ" returns 0
./isrepeated.sh "ĴĴĴ123ĴĴĴ123" returns 0
./isrepeated.sh "abcdefgh" returns 1
$
```

Note `=~` within `[[ ... ]]` is [the regex operator in bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005d_005d).  However *"Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string"*.  So as ai often the case with bash, getting quoting right is very important - here we just want to check for a string submatch and not a regex match.

Answer (score 3):

### TI-BASIC - 32

I thought I'd try a tokenized language. Run with the string in Ans, returns 0 if false and the length of the repeated string if true.

```
inString(sub(Ans+Ans,1,2length(Ans)-1),sub(Ans,length(Ans),1)+Ans
```

Amazing how it's a one-liner.

Comment: But... but... I was going to use TI-BASIC :P +1

Comment: @Timtech Well, note to anyone trying string manipulation in TI-BASIC: Don't try string manipulation in TI-BASIC. :P That was so hard to make and optimize.

Comment: Good idea. String manipulation is one of the hardest things to do. However, I've posted several answers like this, so I guess now you have a competitor ;)

Comment: Bring it on! :P

Answer (score 3):

## ECMAScript 6 (189)

```
(function(){var S=String.prototype,r=S.repeat;S.isRepeated=function(){return!1};S.repeat=function(c){var s=new String(r.call(this,c));if(c>1)s.isRepeated=function(){return!0};return s}}());
```

```
< console.log("abc".isRepeated(),"abc".repeat(10).isRepeated());
> false true
```

Surely this is the only valid solution? For example, the word (string) `nana` isn't necessarily created from `"na".repeat(2)`

Comment: `"nana"` isn't, but the question is not testing whether `.repeat` was used or not. Rather, whether the string is a repeated one or not

Comment: I know, I was just trying to be a smart-arse :P

Answer (score 2):

## ECMAScript 6 (34 <s>36</s>)

Another ES6 answer, but without using `repeat` and using [xnor's trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37855/26765):

```
f=i=>(i+i).slice(1,-1).contains(i)
```

Must be run in the console of a ES6-capable browser such as Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

## C 85

```
l,d;f(s){return l=strlen(s),strstr(d,strcpy(strcpy(d=alloca(l*2+1),s)+l,s)-1)-d-l+1;}
```

It turned out to be quite long but external functions are always like that.
It came to my mind that I could rewrite every string function replacing them by a loop or a recursive one. But in my experience it would turn out longer and frankly I don't want to try that out.

After some research I saw solutions on high performance but not as clever (and short) as xnor's one. just to be original... i rewrote the same idea in c.

explanation:

```c
int length, 
    duplicate;
int is_repetition(char *input)
{
    // length = "abc" -> 3
    length = strlen(input);
    // alloca because the function name is as long as "malloc" 
    // but you don't have to call free() because it uses the stack
    // to allocate memory
    // duplicate = x x x x x x + x
    duplicate = alloca(length*2 + 1);
    // duplicate = a b c 0 x x + x
    strcpy(duplicate, input);
    // duplicate = a b c a b c + 0
    strcpy(duplicate + length, input);
    if (strstr(duplicate,duplicate + length - 1) != duplicate + length - 1)
        // repetition
        // e.g. abab -> abababab -> aba[babab]
        // -> first occurence of [babab] is not aba[babab]
        // but a[babab]ab -> this is a repetition
        return 1;
    else
        // not repetition
        // e.g. abc -> abcabc -> ab[cabc]
        // -> first occurence of [cabc] is ab[cabc]
        // it matches the last "cabc"
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṙJċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w50yvI93///9PSUNAAA)

Same as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121546/41024) (maybe the later challenge is a generalization of this one?).

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6 (59 <s>62</s> <s>67</s> <s>73</s>)

Not a winner, but seems like there should at least be one answer actually in ES6 for this question that actually uses the `repeat` function:

```
f=i=>[...i].some((_,j)=>i.slice(0,j).repeat(i.length/j)==i)
```

Must be run in the console of a ES6-capable browser such as Firefox.

It does a lot of unnecessary iterations, but why make it longer just to avoid that, right?

- *Edit #1:* Saved a few bytes by converting it into a function. Thanks to Optimizer!
- *Edit #2:* Thanks to hsl for the spread operator trick to save more bytes!
- *Edit #3:* And thanks to Rob W. for another 3 bytes!

Comment: You can just convert it into a function to save more bytes there

Comment: @Optimizer True, I guess it doesn't have to be "stdin". Your live up to your name :)

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for `[...i]` instead of `i.split('')`

Comment: @hsl Crazy, that works. I didn't know the spread operator works like that. Originally I desperately tried to use it to create an array with the range `0..N`. Thanks!

Comment: `.slice(0,j)` is one character shorter than `.substr(0,j)`. Further, the conversion to an integer seems unnecessary `|0` can be removed (using `|0` actually reduces the usefulness of the method because it will fail for repetitions that exceed 2^31).

Comment: @RobW Mh, weird. I added the `|0` because I got an error. Doesn't seem to error out now, though, so I guess I really can remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 28 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("(?s)(.+)\\1+")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY/BTsMwDIbvewqrp0TTMg1uTMCN23bZbpSDm6ZrRupUdTppQn0rHoH3KmEtHJBgVWwplv/Pv33EEy58beiYv/baITNs0NLbDMBSME2B2sD2qwTIvHcGCbTYhcbSAViuY6OLGYMDBqthCwT30PPigVWFQZeGRSIeWQo1l2m6mieyXw9E3WYuEiN48jaHKnqP059fUA6@yyXsmzaU57tLuTtzMJXybVB1FAZHgpQWCXJefGciL6v9Lf54//0mIqub25/PVQRTGuI/5diJVz6hYzP1yuvmmc5NcSinbjnqulnXfwI)

**Explanation:**

Checks if the input-String matches the regex, where [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) implicitly adds `^...$` to match the entire String.
Explanation of the regex itself:

```
^(s?)(.+)\1+$
^                Begin of the string
 (s?)            Enable DOTALL-mode, where `.` also matches new-lines
     (           Open capture group 1
      .+          One or more characters
        )        Close capture group 1
         \1+     Plus the match of the capture group 1, one or more times
            $    End of the string
```

So it basically checks if a substring is repeated two or more times (supporting new-lines).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
żḢ/v≈a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwixbzhuKIvduKJiGEiLCIiLCJcImFzZGZhc2RmYXNkZlwiXG5cImFzZGZhc2RmYVwiXG5cIsS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtMS0xLTEtFwiXG5cIsS0xLTEtDEyM8S0xLTEtDEyM1wiXG5cImFiY2RlZmdoXCIiXQ==)

### Explained

```
żḢ/v≈a
  /    # Split the input string into pieces of
żḢ     # range [2, len(input)]
   v≈a # do any of those have all the same item
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>51</s> <s>36</s> 25 bytes

Based on [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252724/11261). Returns the string for truthy and `nil` for falsy.

```
~:[]%(~:*&2|~:[]&(1..-2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWO-usomNVNeqstNSMakBsNQ1DPT1dI01NiPzNjAIFt2ilxOKUNBhWiuVCFYMJHNmCDlFlDI2M4Qy4IUnJKalp6RlKsRD7FiyA0AA)

This is equivalent to the lambda `->s{ (s*2)[1..-2][s] }`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 19 bytes

Another port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37851/string-prototype-isrepeated/37855#37855). Takes input on stdin; prints the string if it's repeated and `nil` otherwise.

```ruby
p ($_*2)[1..-2][$_]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5ejlLsojTbpaUlaboWmwsUNFTitYw0ow319HSNYqNV4mMhMgug1E3XxOKUNBjmgnO4jmxBh1AhQyNjOIMrMSk5JTUtPQNiGgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
²é ¤øU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=sukgpPhV&input=WwoiYXNkZmFzZGZhc2RmIiAKImFzZGZhc2RmYSIKIlx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNCIKIlx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNDEyM1x1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNDEyMyIKImFiY2RlZmdoIgpdLW1S)

Boring copy of the common logic from other answers:

```
²é ¤øU
²      # Duplicate the input
 é     # Move the last character to the front
   ¤   # Remove the first two characters
    øU # Return true if it still contains the input
```

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¬x@¥éY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rHhApelZ&input=WwoiYXNkZmFzZGZhc2RmIiAKImFzZGZhc2RmYSIKIlx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNCIKIlx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNDEyM1x1MDEzNFx1MDEzNFx1MDEzNDEyMyIKImFiY2RlZmdoIgpdLW1S)

More interesting, but has a weirder output; `1` means `false`, any other output means `true`. Identical to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121565/71434) answer on a different challenge, but discovered separately.

Explanation:

```
¬x@¥éY
¬      # Convert input to an array of characters
 x@    # Apply a function to each one, then sum the results:
    éY #  Rotate the input string a number of times equal to the current index
   ¥   #  Return 1 if it's still equal to the input, 0 otherwise
```