# Check if a string is entirely made of the same substring

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

This is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823298/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring) (with permission ofcourse). I'll quote:

> Create a function which takes a string, and it should return true or
>   false based on whether the input consists of ***only*** a repeated character
>   sequence. The length of given string is always greater than 1 and the
>   character sequence must have at least one repetition.

Some examples:

```
'aa' //true
'aaa' //true
'abcabcabc' //true
'aba' //false
'ababa' //false
'weqweqweqweqweqw' // false
```

Specifically, the check for a string strictly composed of repeating substrings (**Update**) can output any true or false representation, but no error output please. Strictly alphhanumeric strings. Otherwise standard code golf rules. This is Code Golf, so shortest answer in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: Hm, I was going to close this challenge as a dupe of [that one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37851/41024), but I noticed that the other one scores on character count. So maybe we should close the other one (it also has an accepted answer) as a dupe of this one instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92837/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-ouflak).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
ġ=Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU5VqQKy0xJziVKXah7s6HzU11D7cOuH/kYW2D3c2/P8frZSYqKQDJMBkUjIEgdkQEQhdnlqIgpRiAQ)

### Explanation

```
ġ=Ṁ    Implicit input, say "abcabc"
ġ      Split into chunks of equal lengths (except maybe the last one): ["abc","abc"]
 =     Apply the constraint that all of the chunks are equal,
  Ṁ    and that there are multiple of them.
```

The program prints `true.` if the constraints can be satisfied, and `false.` if not.

Comment: I was just struggling through trying to get something like `~j↙` or `=Ṁc` working before I noticed you posted this an hour ago

Comment: Oh, yeah, this could be one byte shorter: [`ġ=Ṁ`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU5VqQKy0xJziVKXaciUupfLah1sngMQ8SxSKU1NzixVKMhJLFDwVkorys1MVMnMLUosSSzLLUhUe7upUKM9IzQPKJaakpKYopKQm5yQiJJWApvw/svDhzgbb//@jlRITlXSABJhMSoYgMBsiAqHLUwtRkFIsAA)

Comment: (`Ṁ` is a variable constrained to be a list of two or more elements)

Comment: ([better TIO link](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU5VqQKy0xJziVKXah7s6HzU11D7cOuH/kYW2D3c2/P8frZSYqKQDJMBkUjIEgdkQEQhdnlqIgpRiAQ) now that I've realized why writeln is broken [I forgot to handle default subscript when I updated it for compatibility with declarative write])

Comment: I guess I'll just edit?

Comment: If I messed anything up feel free to roll it back

Comment: @UnrelatedString Great, thanks! I didn't think to check the variables wiki page.

Comment: `Ṁ` was added pretty recently, so if you hadn't checked it in the past week or two (or been in the chat room, where it was announced) you'd have no idea it's there. It's certainly not the most intuitive place to look unless you're already in the habit of using `Ċ` wherever you'd think to use `l₂`.

Comment: A lot of great answers, and the LUA answer has a special place in my heart. Arnauld's answer is particularly sweet since the original question that I based this on (not the dupe) is actually tagged Javascript. Mainly selecting this one just because it does appear to be the overall shortest for all languages and, as this is my first question, I get a badge.

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
s=>/^(.*)\1+$/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k4/TkNPSzPGUFtFX68ktbhEo1jzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGemKiugIEaGoq6OuXFJWmcmEoganBrSQpGYLU8ShBMSUtMacYmxqoKoSa/wA)

---

## Without a regular expression,  <s>33</s>  29 bytes

Returns either `null` (falsy) or an object (truthy).

```javascript
s=>(s+s).slice(1,-1).match(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k6jWLtYU684JzM5VcNQR9dQUy83sSQ5Q6NY839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahnpioroCBGhqKujrlxSVpnJhKIGpwa0kKRmC1PEoQTElLTGnGJsaqCqEmv8A)

NB: Technically, \$s\$ is converted to a regular expression for *match()*, so the above title is a lie.

Answer (score 10):

## grep, 19

```
grep -qxE '(.+)\1+'
```

#### Test

```
while read; do 
  <<<"$REPLY" grep -qxE '(.+)\1+' && t="true" || t="false"
  echo "$REPLY: $t"
done < infile
```

Output:

```
aa: true
aaa: true
abcabcabc: true
aba: false
ababa: false
weqweqweqweqweqw: false
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
²é ¤øU
```

Saved one byte thanks to @Shaggy

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CmwysVDi05vCP0//9o9cREdR0uIAmhkpIhCMKBioEYsQq6uUEA)

```
        Implicit input, stored in variable 'U'
²       U+U, "abcabc" -> "abcabcabcabc"
 é      Rotate 1 char to the right "abcabcabcabc" -> "cabcabcabcab"
   ¤    Remove first two chars, "cabcabcabcab" -> "bcabcabcab"
    øU  Check if U is in the above
```

Comment: Nice one :) You can replace the `p<space>` with `²` to save a byte.

Answer (score 9):

## Java, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Olivier Grégoire!
Boring regex answer

```java
s->s.matches("(.+)\\1+")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY09b8IwEIZ3/4oTky2Epa6JisQAWyfG0uFibHDq2KnvQoWi/HbXtF2QnvuS7tHb4w03/fmzmIBE8IY@zsJHttmhsXCYu5SCxQhOHjn7eAFS7SLGqQveADFyHbfkzzBU9f/n/QMwX0jN4gAOXgtttqQHZHO1JFdSr9Xp9LJeqdKKvubriX3Qu5zxTpo4Wxzkr1@dUbqmcUq7lPdorvJ4J7aDThM3zVizOETVimUpBbFSqzN/1O1xPfq3/XriBw)
<s>*It's just 1 byte longer than the python answer aaaaa*</s> I'm tied now :)

Comment: You can remove the final `$` as the `matches` method is an exact match, not a substring match by default.

Comment: I forgot `matches` adds its own `$` to the regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Excel, 26 bytes

```
=FIND(A1,A1&A1,2)<=LEN(A1)
```

Inputs from A1, outputs to whatever cell you put this formula.

Comment: You could save 4 bytes if you defined a single-letter range name (e.g. `A`) and set that as your input.

Comment: @i_saw_drones - I think that is disallowed by standard I/O rules: here's a link to the [meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/78915) that would apply to that method; it's currently at -36 votes.

Comment: Apologies I hadn't seen that post, although thinking about it, isn't `A1` also a "variable" since it contains the input value? :)

Comment: I would feel that way if I were doing anything special with the fact that it's A1 specifically, like if I relied somehow on its ROW(_) being 1. As is, though, it's just the most natural way of providing an Excel function with an arbitrary input.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
grepl("(.+)\\1+$",scan(,''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P70otSBHQ0lDT1szJsZQW0VJpzg5MU9DR11dU/O/UmISMlTiAgokgxGQWZ5aCEFIbJCKRLAyMAkCSv8B)

Simple Regex version. R is (sometimes) very similar to Python, so this is similar to TFeld's Python 2 regex answer, albeit shorter!

#### Question (if anyone knows the answer)

I am still confused why this works, as the substring can be any length and will always work, and still works when I add a letter to the front of a valid string, like "cABABABABAB". If I personally read the regex, I see `(.+)`, which captures any group of any length. And then `\\1+$` which repeats the captured group any number of times until the end.

So why doesn't it capture just "AB" and find that it is repeated until the end of the string, especially since there is no restriction specified as to where the substring can start?

Comment: Interesting, this seems to be a bug in R's regex engine. Adding the option `perl=TRUE` makes it match cABABAB, as you'd expect. Running `grep -E '(.*)\1+$'` in bash also matches cABABAB, even though `grep -E` uses ERE, the same regex flavor R is supposed to support.

Comment: My guess is that this is an incorrectly applied optimization. Changing `.+` at the start of a pattern to `^.+` is an important optimization, but if the `.+` is inside capturing parens it stops being valid.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 9 bytes

```
^(.+)\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP05DT1szxlBb5f//xESuRBBOSoYgIAvEA0IA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

I see now that the optimal way is to follow [xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37855/53748)!

```
Ḋ;Ṗw
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and outputs an integer - the  shortest possible length of a repeating slice or zero if none exists. Note that zero is falsey while non-zero numbers are truthy in Jelly.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hji7rhzunlf///z8xKRmKAA)**

#### How?

```
Ḋ;Ṗw - Link: list of characters, S   e.g. "abcabcabc"   or "abababa"
Ḋ    - dequeue S                           "bcabcabc"       "bababa"
  Ṗ  - pop from S                         "abcabcab"       "ababab"
 ;   - concatenate                "bcabcabcabcabcab"       "bababaababab"
   w - first index of sublist     3  ^---here!             0  (not found)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda s:s in(s*2)[1:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghM0@jWMtIM9rQStcw9n9BUWZeiUKahnpiorqmsoK@fklRaSoXkih24aRkCMIuCdYDFE9LzClGlcAlVZ5aiIKgqhTQTYDYBxb9DwA)

Shamelessly stolen from [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37855/38592) to the original question.

---

More intuitive version:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda s:s in[len(s)/i*s[:i]for i in range(1,len(s))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghMy86JzVPo1hTP1OrONoqMzYtv0ghEyisUJSYl56qYagDkdaM/V9QlJlXopCmoZ6YqK6prKCvX1JUmsqFJIpdOCkZgrBLgvUAxdMSc4pRJXBJlacWoiCoKgWwsv8A)

---

**Boring regex version:**

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.match(r'(.+)\1+$',s)>0
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqihVLzexJDlDo0hdQ09bM8ZQW0Vdp1jTzoArM7cgv6hEoSj1f0FRZl6JQpqGemKiuqaygr5@SVFpKheSKHbhpGQIwi4J1gMUT0vMKUaVwCVVnlqIgqCqFMDK/gMA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 14 bytes

```perl
$_=/^(.*)\1+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/TkNPSzPGUFtF////xH/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>26 25 15</s></sup> 14 bytes

Using xnor method

```
+./@E.}:@}.@,~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfX0HVz1aq0cavUcdOr@a3KlJmfkK6QpqCcmqisgcRLVEZykZAiCChko2EKEEzEE0IXKUwtRkPp/AA)

### original (two different approaches)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
1<1#.(#%#\)=<\+/@E.&:>"{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DW0MlfU0lFWVYzRtbWK09R1c9dSs7JSqY/9rcqUmZ@QrpCmoJyaqKyBxEtURnKRkCIIKGSjYQoQTMQTQhcpTC1GQ@n8A)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 26 bytes

```
1<1#.-@#\([:(-:##{.)<\)"{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DW0MlfV0HZRjNKKtNHStlJWr9TRtYjSVqmP/a3KlJmfkK6QpqCcmqisgcRLVEZykZAiCChko2EKEEzEE0IXKUwtRkPp/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
+tO{
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2BtO%7B&input=abcabc&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
+    -    input+input
 t   -   ^[1:]
  O  -  ^[:-1]
   { - input in ^
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
StringMatchQ[x__..~~x_]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7ikKDMv3TexJDkjMLoiPl5Pr66uIj72fwBQuMRBK03foZpLKTFRSQdEQqikZAiCcKBiUEZ5aiESKi8sV6r9DwA)

```
StringMatchQ[           (*a function that checks if its input (string) matches:*)
             x__..      (*a sequence of one or more characters, repeated one or more times*)
                  ~~x_] (*and one more time*)
```

Answer (score 4):

## GNU Bash, 28 bytes

```
[[ ${1:1}${1::-1} == *$1* ]]
```

Save the above script into a file, and run `bash file.sh "string to test"`.

Exit code 0 is truthy and non-zero is falsy. (as all Unix shells would interpret)

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>23</s> 24 bytes

+1 byte to fully match rules

```
"$args"-match"^(.+)\1+$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0klsSi9WEk3N7EkOUMpTkNPWzPGUFtF6T9QKjEpGYiUAA)

Pretty boring. Based on the other Regex answers. Luckily PowerShell doesn't use `\` as an escape character!

Comment: it returns `true` for `aabcabc`

Comment: @mazzy just fixed!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

[xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37855/47066) from the previous question appears to be optimal in 05AB1E as well.

```
«¦¨så
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0OpDyw6tKD689P//xKRkCAIA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVllZ@f/Q6kPLDq0oPrz0v45mzP/ERK5EEE5KhiAgC8QDkeWphSgIAA)

**Explanation**

```
«       # append input to input
 ¦¨     # remove the first and last character of the resulting string
   så   # check if the input is in this string
```

Comment: Of course.. I was about to make a 05AB1E answer when I saw none were there. Colleague asked me some questions and talked about his vacation. I look back at the screen: one new answer. Tada, beat again XD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: That's typical. Has happened to me a bunch of times as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

### [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 70 bytes

xnor's shameless adaptation (**46 bytes**)

```
s=>(s+s).Substring(1,s.Length*2-2).Contains(s)
```

My non Regex Solution:

```
s=>s.Select((x,y)=>y).Count(z=>s.Replace(s.Substring(0,z+1),"")=="")>1
```

Explanation:

Replace every possible substring that starts at index 0 with an empty string. If the result is an empty string, the string is entirely made of that substring. Since this includes evaluating the entire string with itself, the amount of expected results must be greater than 1.

Example: **abcabc**

Possible substrings starting at index 0:

```
'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abca', 'abcab', 'abcabc'
```

If we replace them with empty strings

```
Substring          Result

'a'         =>     'bcbc'
'ab'        =>     'cc'
'abc'       =>     ''
'abca'      =>     'bc'
'abcab'     =>     'c'
'abcabc'    =>     ''
```

Since there is a substring other than 'abcabc' that returns an empty string, the string is entirely made of another substring ('abc')

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYuxCsIwFEV3v6JkesFY7KzJIjg56eCcPF4lEBJtErT9@djSSQxc7nDuuRh3GG05Z4/HmAbrH8KE4FTTN7JEqWJ7I0eYAD5i5FKNvD2F7BNMy3alp9NIMFvZrHfYi2nbccEYl3Iu1ZXD5j7YRBfrCXpgWjPO/1gNGlxTm6p@Fb/p9ZPFKF8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>62</s> <s>60</s> <s>56</s> 54 bytes

*-4 bytes thanx to [ArBo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82577/arbo)*

```python
lambda s:s in(len(s)//l*s[:l]for l in range(1,len(s)))
```

1. Iterate over all possible prefixes in the string.
2. Try to build the string out of the prefix.
3. Return whether this succeeds with any prefix at all.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghM08jJzVPo1hTXz9HqzjaKic2Lb9IIQcorlCUmJeeqmGoA5HX1PxfUJSZV6KRpqGUqKSpyYXgoXPR@EnJEIQmiq4KXaQ8tRAFASX/AwA)

Comment: Nice answer! The `f=` can be dropped; anonymous functions are generally allowed. Also, by switching to Python 2 and checking membership of a list instead of the `any` construct, you can get to [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlghMy@6ONoqJ1ZLIyc1T6NYUz9HMy2/SCEHKKFQlJiXnqphqAOR0Yz9X1CUmVeikaahlKikqcmF4KFz0fhJyRCEJoquCl2kPLUQBQEl/wMA)

Comment: Nice catch with the list membership, thanx!
I won't switch to Python 2, as this is like switching the language, which is obviously not the point here ;)

Also, is there a convenient way to test an anonymous function in TIO, keeping the byte-count?

Comment: @movatica In the header, put `f = \` (\ is the line continuation character in python)

Comment: Annoyingly, \ is also an escape character. Here, without code formatting, is what you should put in the header: f = \

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>16</s> 13 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)

For completeness, more or less the same as the other regex answers. Prints `0` for truthy, `nil` for falsey.

```ruby
p~/^(.+)\1+$/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyCpaUlaboWawvq9OM09LQ1Ywy1VfQhYlCpBTe1ExO5EkE4KRmCgCwQD0SWpxaiIIgeAA)

Comment: 13 bytes `p~/^(.+)\1+$/`. `~` is equivalent to `rxp =~ $_`.

Comment: @south Oops! Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

*Returns a positive number if truthy and 0 if falsey. If you want a bool output just add `-¡` flag*

```
å+ k@rXÃÊÉ
```

---

```
å+ k@rXÃÊÉ      Full program. Implicit input U.
                    e.g: U = "abcabcabc"
å+              Take all prefixes 
                         U = ["a","ab","abc","abca","abcab","abcabc","abcabca","abcabcab","abcabcabc"]
   k@           Filter U by:
     rXÃ        Values that return false (empty string)
                when replacing each prefix in U
                e.g: ["bcbcbc","ccc","","bcabc","cabc","abc","bc","c",""]
                                take ↑                             and ↑
                     U = ["abc","abcabcabc"]
         ÊÉ     Get U length and subtract 1. Then return the result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///BSbYVsh6KIw82Huw53/v8frZ6YqK7DBSQhVFIyBEE4UDEQI1ZBNzcIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
Ṡ€ȯhtD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBY@a1pxYn1Hi8v//f6XEpGQIUgIA)

I feel like this is one byte more than optimal, but I couldn't find an arrangement that made the explicit composition `ȯ` unnecessary.

## Explanation

```
Ṡ€      Find the argument in the result of applying the following function to the argument
  ȯhtD  Duplicate the argument, then remove the first and last elements.
```

Comment: `€htD¹` avoids the `ȯ`.

Comment: That's fantastic! I had thought about `λ€htD¹` but I didn't realize that lambdas would be added implicitly

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 11.x, 74 bytes

```
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&
```

where, throughout, `#` represents the input string, and

```
StringCases[#,<pattern>]
```

finds substrings of the input string matching the pattern

```
StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")
```

This pattern requires matches, `x`, must start at the start of the string and must satisfy the condition that (1) the match is not the whole input string and (2) if we replace occurrences of the match in the input string with the empty string we obtain the empty string.  Finally, comparing the list of matches to the empty list,

```
{}!=
```

is `True` if the list of matches is nonempty and `False` if the list of matches is empty.

Test cases:

```
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["aa"]
(*  True  *)
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["aaa"]
(*  True  *)
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["abcabc"]
(*  True  *)
```

and

```
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["aba"]
(*  False  *)
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["ababa"]
(*  False  *)
{}!=StringCases[#,StartOfString~~x__/;(x!=#&&StringReplace[#,x->""]=="")]&["weqweqweqweqweqw"]
(*  False  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 84 bytes

```
import textwrap
lambda s:any(len(set(textwrap.wrap(s,l)))<2 for l in range(1,len(s)))
```

Uses `textwrap.wrap` (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860937/4533885)) to split the string into pieces of length `n` to test each possible length of repeating substring. The split pieces are then compared to each other by adding them to a set. If all of the pieces are equal, and the set is of length 1, then the string must be a repeating string. I used `<2` instead of `==1` because it saves a byte, and the length of the input string was guaranteed to be greater than zero.

If there is no `n` for which repeating substrings of length `n` make up the entire string, then return false for the whole function.

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

```cpp
#define f(x)(x+x).find(x,1)<x.size()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNDsIgEIX3nGJCF0KsGrcV60XcIKUNiUItVInGs1faGu2PL5MALx9vYERZrgohmkhpca4zCUwZ6yrJLyn6ecFRuhg6NymcqdImymSutISceEr80tN1OGbEx1vK/NqqhyS0UdrBhSsNhMITQZAw2jqwLkuSPol1@08fULqsHew/cCvMOY5hrM3GVbUcIjNmhpxEXz9wjvxJyfnZjpkpNWPu8jqqgA@Z1w51a24qILx2Bjwk/cfpN6QbijBhFmjYizEg7cDhALh9PA43cReN6RRcHPVih17NGw)

Another port of xnor's solution. Uses a macro to expand the argument into the expression. The argument is assumed to be of type `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 73 bytes

*Doesn't use regex.*

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
$s=or[isPrefixOf s(cycle t)\\t<-tl(tails s)|t>[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy7CsIwFEB3vyJDoS1Yv8A61UEoWOiYZrikiVzIQ3Ovj4Lfbiw4CWc5wznaGQjZx/nujPCAIaO/xsRi5PkYHtsOGHY9Em8KamOSSEMyFl9nK6jSi14rrqeJ9w27igEdCarffJBK5ZFhHbWiELJ8mtsfpcofbR1cKDenPndLAI/6J4MDtjH5Lw)

Defines `$ :: [Char] -> Bool`.
Checks if the given string is a prefix of the repetition of any sub-string taken from the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 19 bytes

Outputs via error code:

```sh
[[ $1$1 = ?*$1*? ]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPVZxaoqCrq6ACEvgfHa2gYqhiqGCrYK@lYqhlrxAb@z81OSNfQcWeKyUfqCCRKxGEgDgpMQlMgCggCaO4AA)

However, the challenge did specify "output on stdout":

#### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 22 bytes

Outputs an empty string if true, and a non-empty string for false:

```sh
<<<${${:-$1$1}/?*$1*?}
```

If the output must be fixed:

#### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

Outputs `0` for true, `1` for false

```sh
[[ $1$1 = ?*$1*? ]]
<<<$?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPVZxaoqCrq6ACEvgfHa2gYqhiqGCrYK@lYqhlrxAby2VjY6Ni/z8lHyidyJUIQkCclJgEJkAUkIRRXAA)

---

The heart of these solutions is `?*$1*?`, which is a glob which matches the string in question surrounded by at least one character on each side: `*` is a string of any length, and `?` is a single character.  This is an alternate version of xnor's solution, but using globs to match extra characters rather than removing leading and trailing characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
dḢṪc
```

*-1 byte by porting [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37851/string-prototype-isrepeated/37855#37855) from the other question*

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyQSIsIiIsImThuKLhuapjIiwiIiwiJ2FhJ1xuJ2FhYSdcbidhYmNhYmNhYmMnXG4nYWJhJ1xuJ2FiYWJhJ1xuJ3dlcXdlcXdlcXdlcXdlcXcnIl0=)

Concatenates the string to itself, removes the first and last characters, then checks if the input string is in that.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
&/1_=':#'=:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1LTN4y3VbdSVre14uJKi1ZKTEqGIKVYCDcRzkhCsICyANfzEKQ=)

*Thanks to PyGamer0 for the "check if all the values of a list are equal" code snippet!*

Return `1` for true and `0` for false

Explanations:

```
&/1_=':#'=:  Main function. Takes implicit input with : on the right-most
         =   Group the characters into a dictionary
       #'    Get the length in the values of each of the keys
             (The values are the occurence positions of the characters in the string)
      :      Apply everything on the left to the right
    ='       Check if the values of the values in the dictionary are equal
  1_         Weed out the first one (as we know it will always be false)
&/           Get the minimum value
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 47 bytes

Using @Xnor's [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37851/string-prototype-isrepeated/37855#37855):

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='ababab'

PRINT sign(charindex(@,left(@+@,len(@)*2-1),2))
```

Keeping old answer as it contains some nice golfing(67 bytes):

```sql
DECLARE @y varchar(max)='abababa'

,@ INT=0WHILE
replace(@y,left(@y,@),'')>''SET
@+=1PRINT @/len(@y)^1
```

**Explanation:** This script is repeatingly trying to replace the input '@y' with the first '@' characters of the input '@y' with nothing, while increasing '@'.

> if you replace 'ab' in 'ababab' with nothing you have an empty string

Eventually the result will be empty. If this happens when the loop variable is equal to the length of the varchar, the criteria is false/0 because '@'=len(@y) (there was no repeating varchar).

```
iif(@=len(@y),0,1)
```

can be golfed into this

```
@/len(@y)^1
```

because the length of '@y' can not be 0 and '@' will never exceed the length @y.

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1037448/check-if-a-string-is-entirely-made-of-the-same-substring)**

Answer (score 1):

## QlikView Variable, 27 bytes

This should be defined as a variable, which then allows you to pass parameters, e.g. `$1` as your input value.

It returns `0` or `-1` (equivalent to QlikView's `TRUE()` function).

```
=substringcount($1&$1,$1)>2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 196 bytes

```
func r(s:String)->Bool{guard let k=s.dropFirst().firstIndex(where:{$0==s.first}) else{return false};let v=s[...k].dropLast();var w=v;while s.hasPrefix(w) && s.count>=(w+v).count{w+=v};return s==w}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BC4JAEIX/yiIhLtHSoZOyHjoEQYegY3RYdFYXZa2ZdTcQf7updQkGHu/x@OZRMNodpkn3tmCYUHpzaGzFd/mx69qh6hWWrAXHGkmixO55Mkgu4UIverYlvJNQA0I6bPZy7qz5yBm0BAOC69EyrWYzZgvGS7oLIZrHCruohZV5hSxIn4XatMBI1IquCNrMaM7ieE6Krrcul0nYev41Q9hKP2a/DyRlGKdlfxTg9XcRnz4)

Comment: I don't use Swift, but I'm sure that extra whitespace can be removed

Comment: [193 bytes](https://tio.run/##Vc7BCoJAEAbgV1kkxCVaOnRS1kOHIOgQdIwOi87qoqw1s@4G4rObWpdgYPh/ho@hYLQ7TJPubcEwofTm0NiK7/Jj17VD1SssWQuONZJEid3zZJBcwoVe9tmW8E5CDQjpsNnL@WbtRw4twYDgerRMqzmM2aJ4SXchRPNYrYtaqMwrZEH6LNSmBUaiVnRF0GaWeRyTKLreulwmYev5NwxhK/2Y/XySMozT8nwU4PU3EZ8@ "Swift 4 – Try It Online") using @benjamin's suggestion.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl or even [123 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184835/78364)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 46 bytes

```
procedure f(s);return find(s,(s||s)[2:-1]);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU67DsIwDJzpV5hMsdQOMLaCH6k6hMYRkSABJ6VC6r@XhHQA6@Tz83R29G5dH@xH0hMTGBmwY4oTOzDWaRlqGZYlYH9sm8OAHTn9c35X1kmsIEWkEAO0J@iFUqKGlAtdxoLSbLOtmOn5BzHsvmL0In7D7FlnxX3R1h7kzDaSzIv0Dc0Zkoo1yXYeIcQrORCRJxJAt0AgjEokEKts/AM)

Another port of xnor's solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 29 bytes

```
{0<+/(1=#?:)'(0N,'1_!#x)#\:x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82q2sBGW1/D0FbZ3kpTXcPAT0fdMF5RuUJTOcaqovZ/mrqGUmKikjWQAJNJyRAEZkNEIHR5aiEKUtL8DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 72 bytes

```
func[s][repeat i length? s[parse s[copy t i skip some t end(return 1)]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYoxDgIxDAT7e4WVCkpaGv5AG7kIiQMR4DN2TideHw7RYGmk1eyuUhlnKhGnehx14RwNo5JQ6tDgQXzttxNYlKRGW@ZZ3vCd7N4EbH7SZsRlp9QXZTjsEXGINu5QIaQUpj9xdsk/XOcf3ld6OcL4AA)

Returns `1` for `True`

Answer (score 1):

## sed, 48

Using the more efficient algorithm described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840779/1331399):

```
s=abcabc
<<<"$s" sed -nE 's/.*/&\n&&/; /^([^\n]+)\n..*\1.*.$/!q5' \
  && echo true \
  || echo false
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 14 bytes

```
length(Ans)>inString(Ans+Ans,Ans,2
```

Input is a string in `Ans`.
Output is true (1) or false (0) as requested by the challenge.

**Examples:**

```
"HELLO
HELLO
prgmCDGF17
               0
"AB
AB
prgmCDGF17
               0
"ABAB
ABAB
prgmCDGF17
               1
```

**Explanation:**

```
length(Ans)>inString(Ans+Ans,Ans,2   ;full program

            inString(                ;get the index of
                             Ans,    ; the input in
                     Ans+Ans,        ; the input concatenated with itself
                                 2   ; starting at the second character
                                     ; (returns index of concatenated piece
                                     ;  if not found elsewhere)
length(Ans)                          ;and then get the length of the input
           >                         ;is the length greater than the index?
                                     ; result is left in "Ans"
                                     ; 1 if true, 0 if false
                                     ;implicit print of "Ans"
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 37 bytes

```c
#define f(x)strcmp(strstr(1+x x,x),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5BCsIwEAXQfU8xTBESrBa3KnoRNzFNaqCNtU0xIJ49jopgwaYOHwZ@mEfkopQypMbKqi8UbDtXmPPytEu@q9bYkrqQFkobq0Azz6mVdcNoUdhq7sFnnlOCsQ5qYSwwDrcEaBoCnGY46w4WMzpHIZDv0bW9wjVqUXUK@QaGk@fP91FgWogDR/lOhJkA/vnBqx8XJo24cFWXQX5hH@EeHg)

Yet another port of xnor's solution.
Using C macros to create the concatenated string, where the macro assumes the argument is a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
{?/^(.+)$0+$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v9peP05DT1tTxUBbRb/2vzVXcWKlglqahlJiEhAqaSILJEMQmiAyNxm7IhQOmPcfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4.2/Xcode 10.2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>123</s> 84 bytes

```swift
(1...s.count-1).contains{s==String(repeating:String(s.prefix($0)),count:s.count/$0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY4xC8IwEIX3/opQHBKw0YJToQ6Cg4M41D@Q1osGalpzKVVKf3sMbRc3CbzhcXffe4e9knbnZKcrgtYofT/hUVtloP6cxQ0u8vqAQjyh6Mp5TzErJsNIsieHpqnJQAzYzmhHU8458qrptE1S5o22QmkcMM9niBpoQVjvlhSKvDUg1ZuutoytJzRbIjZ@NLoxilp/aenf/8VCxIwFUGFYWc0KgwM7A8EeXj/yGe4L)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC 3, 72 bytes

Prints `1` for true and `0` for false.

```
LINPUT L$W=LEN(L$)FOR I=1TO W/2IF LEFT$(L$,I)*(W/I)==L$THEN?1STOP
NEXT?0
```

### Explained

```
LINPUT L$       'read line of input
W=LEN(L$)       'store length of input
FOR I=1 TO W/2  'loop over all prefixes
 'if this prefix repeated to length of input equals input, print 1 and stop
 IF LEFT$(L$,I)*(W/I)==L$ THEN ?1 STOP
NEXT
?0              'print 0 because check failed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
*~~/^(.+)$0+$/
```

Or for the same amount

```perl6
{m/^(.+)$0+$/}
```

Much the same as other answers with a simple regex.  First one uses Whatever block and a smart matcher to run the regex, and the second does a match on the block input with the implied value.  Both return Match objects which are truthy on success, and Nil which is falsey on fairly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX6uuTj9OQ09bU8VAW0X/vzVXcWKlgr1amoZ6YqK6JjI3KRmCsIpaqGv@BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 50 bytes

Another port of xnor's solution:

```lua
s=io.read()t=s..s print(s.find(t.sub(t,2,#t-1),s))
```

Prints indexes if true, 'nil' otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2DYzX68oNTFFQ7PEtlhPr1ihoCgzr0SjWC8tMy9Fo0SvuDRJo0THSEe5RNdQU6dYU/P///LUQhQEAA)